# Async function returns a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I found an example on the web that looks like the following:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    return Promise.resolve(123);
}
asyncFunc()
  .then(x => console.log(x)) // 123
```

However, I can also write it like that:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    return 123
}
asyncFunc()
  .then(x => console.log(x)) // 123
```

I mean, I can find a use case for returning a resolved answer (for example, memoization/caching), But why should I actually use it if I can simply return the result, straightforward?

Comment: If you aren't returning an async function/promise, then there's no need to use async.

Comment: the second case makes no sense.  promises are great for async.  the second case is not async.

Comment: Would you like to tell us where on the web you found this example? Without any more context, this looks really odd.

Comment: Well it's just an example. In the actual code, you'd use a promise with a proper purpose, not `Promise.resolve`. Otherwise, why use this particular `asyncFunc` at all? You can get the same result by simply executing `console.log(123)`.

Comment: the thing about examples is, out of context they can look pretty pointless - I can't see what that first example is trying to show, other than it's authors lack of knowledge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function:

> When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. **When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value.**  When the async function throws an exception or some value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value.

Emphasis mine.

Both your examples are totally valid, although returning a resolved promise in the first case is unnecessary. Any async function that returns a plain value will wrap that value into a resolved promise automatically. I think typically people prefer the second example, as it's more straightforward.

Comment: I agree that the `async` version with no explicit promise is cleaner, but the unfortunate truth is that many are not aware of this feature and can cause a lot of confusion.